# the line is not being a line, and instead a point?

Tags: p5.js

I am making a new 2.5d engine but making a better wall system, but the line is not drawing, or rx and ry are resetting? I have no idea what is going on, please help. it only happens when I make the if in the line part of rays was added. As a note, I am using openprossesing
[the line that isn't lineing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN7R6.png)

```
function preload(){
    fov=60;
    x=windowWidth/2;
    y=windowHeight/2;
    angleMode(DEGREES);
    dir=0;
    img = loadImage('eeee.png');
}
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    background(127);
    image(img,0,0);
}

function draw() {
    erase();
    setup();
    if(keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)){
        x+=2*sin(dir);
        y+=2*cos(dir);
    }
    if(keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)){
        dir+=1;
    }
    if(keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)){
        dir-=1;
    }
    rays();
}

function rays(){
    rx=x;
    ry=y;
    rdir=dir-fov/2;
    for(let i = 0; i < fov; i++){
        for(let i = 0; i < 350; i++){
            c = img.get(rx, ry);
            if(c===127, 127, 127, 127){
                line(x,y,rx,ry);
            }else{
                rx+=1*sin(rdir);
                ry+=1*cos(rdir);
            }
        }
        line(x,y,rx,ry);
        rdir+=2;
    }
}
```

oops almost forgot
[the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X62zd.png)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide a detailed answer at the moment.
If you're telling p5.js to draw lines and it looks like points that's a pretty good place to start debugging (e.g. add `console.log(x,y,rx,ry);` before your `line()` call to check the maths adds up (you don't have two very close points (a tiny line that looks like a point). You can also use the browser's Developer Tools to set a breakpoint and step through each calculation to verify it does what you expect and isolate the edge case). Good luck!

Comment: console.log, print, and debug() are not working. i do not know why

Comment: Strange: can post your code + image on https://editor.p5js.org/ ? Does the Developer Tools Console in your browser show any errors ? (Maybe  the program gets stuck at an error before the console log message get to show ? (Stepping through with the debugger should still work though). You might also find these Coding Train resources helpful: [1](https://thecodingtrain.com/challenges/145-ray-casting-2d), [2](https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/Nqsq3DFv-) , [3](https://thecodingtrain.com/challenges/146-rendering-ray-casting), [4](https://editor.p5js.org/codingtrain/sketches/yEzlR0_zq)